# Match port in Chrome extension pattern

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Reading this list of Chrome match patterns: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html

How do I specify a match for a URL that depends on a port? Like

```
http://localhost:8080
http://kevinburke.com:5000/index.php
```

for example.

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You get access to all ports.

```
"http://localhost/*", "http://kevinburke.com/*"
```